# Display selected item from dropdown onchange function into html label through JavaScript , please help how to it

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<form  method="post">
  <select name="users" id="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" value="">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1" onchange="copy();">tcs</option>
    <option value="2" onchange="copy();">wipro</option>
    <option value="3" onchange="copy();">Hcl</option>
    <option value="4" onchange="copy();">krystal kones</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I have this drop down I want that when the value is changed like tcs, wipro or hcl then that value should shown in html label.

Answer (score 14):

Try putting the `onChange` attribute in the `select` tag.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6Fus/

HTML:

```
<div id="label"></div>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="copy();">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="tcs" >tcs</option>
    <option value="wipro" >wipro</option>
    <option value="Hcl" >Hcl</option>
    <option value="krystal kones" >krystal kones</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function copy() {
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect").value
}
```

Otherwise you could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the `onchange` event is for the `select` element, not the `option` elements.  Those don't actually change.  Also, you have two JavaScript functions.  `showUser()` and `copy()`.  But you describe only one piece of functionality.  What do these two functions do?

As for showing the text in the label, here's one way to do it (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), because everybody does):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#users').change(function() {
    $('#myLabel').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

What this is basically doing is:

1. Wait until the DOM is loaded and ready.
2. Bind a function to the `change` event of the [specified](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) `select` element.
3. The function contains one line, which sets the text of the specified label to the value of the `select`.