# Populating a page using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

This is a whole new area for me so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, hopefully a good tutorial?

I have a page with a drop down list, based on the users selection from the list I need to populate the page.

Could anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial that does something similar?

This is the order of things I need to do:

1. Page loads
2. User selects a value from a HTML drop down list
3. Another PHP page returns the array related to that selection.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery:

```
$('#id-of-your-select').change(function() {

  $.ajax({

    method: 'post',
    url: 'yourscript.php',
    data: '?theValue=of&your=dropdown',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#div-to-be-populated').html(data);
    }
  });
 });
```

and in your php:

```
<?php

switch($_GET['dropdownvalue'] {

  case 'hello':
    echo '<p>Hello World<p>';
  break;
}
?>
```

of couse you have to configure it to your need, but i hope you get the basic idea

Comment: Hi, could you explain what I need to do with the "?theValue=of&your=dropdown" field?

Comment: that line is for the post or get parameters you send for the value of the dropdown you do:

`$('#id-of-dropdown option:selected).val()`

in the line you need its:

`data: '?value='+$('#id-of-dropdown option:selected').val(),`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

This tutorial will make you an expert in AJAX and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need two PHP Pages and AJAX knowledge.

1. PHP Page1 (May be HTML) load normal page
2. On browser, you need to capture 'onChange' event for dropdown to call a function.
3. Under that function, make AJAX request to your second PHP page.
4. Do needful with returned data with PHP Page 2.

That is simple list of what should happen.

I assume you are fine with step 1.

For Step 2, You need to learn basic javascript. Just google how to capture onChange Event. Few quick links are:
[display selected item from dropdown onchange function into html label through javascript , please help how to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315437/display-selected-item-from-dropdown-onchange-function-into-html-label-through-ja)

For Step 3, I suggest do not go for shortcut but go through full AJAX tutorial at
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Once you finish that tutorial, you will be doing things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a very simple way by using jquery. 
jquery is the best solution for this type of problem. important links are: http://jquery.com
and also you can learn from w3schools for better jquery knowledge.